# Open terminal from nautilus by right click

Tags: command-line, nautilus

I use nautilus as my default file manager. Is there any way that I can customize it so that right click anywhere in the window gives an option to open the current directory in terminal. I have seen same feature in dolphin, wish I could do the same in nautilus too.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Install `nautilus-open-terminal`. In a terminal type:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal
```

Once it installs, type `nautilus -q && nautilus &` to quit and reopen nautilus, and check the right click option.

Comment: there is no need to log out and log back in. 
just go to terminal and write 
    $ sudo killall -9 nautilus

and once again writing 
    $ nautilus

works fine.

Comment: or simply `nautilus -q && nautilus&`

Comment: Verified on 16.04

Comment: I can't find this package in the 17.10 repos, however in default Nautilus if I go one level up in the directory hierarchy, I can right-click the folder and there is "open in terminal" option.

Comment: According to top answer in the linked duplicate question, there is another package in the new Ubuntu versions - `nautilus-actions`.

Answer (score 6):

I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal
nautilus -q
```

Then just click the file manager window, and then try right clicking anywhere and the option "Open in Terminal" is right there!

Answer (score 1):

To open a terminal from Nautilus, you must install the package nautilus-open-terminal (sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal from the command line). In the context menu is the option to open a terminal in the current directory.