# Is there a command to get the location of a file which is selected in nautilus?

Tags: command-line, nautilus

I want to be able to select a file, enter a command and have it return the current location of the file selected in a terminal.

Comment: unclear. Be specific. How did you open that file?

Comment: I have just clicked on it in nautilus, it has the orange selection, I haven't opened it.

Comment: What is the use case? Are you trying to automate something, or is it just a convenience?

Comment: It is to copy the file to a shared folder when I drag it to the side of the screen.

Comment: @Tim, What's the deference, adding that shared folder to bookmakes on side panel. It seems same, you just need to drag it (with Ctrl key pressed for copying)

Comment: Simply user preference, and it would be more in keeping with the way I have my desktop set up.

Comment: To reference a previous thread - link[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/293566/open-terminal-from-nautilus-by-right-click

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a file name into a terminal program, you should be able to use either mouse drag'n'drop or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-(<kbd>Shift</kbd>-)<kbd>v</kbd> to copy/paste it into an editor/terminal.

Comment: Is there a way without dragging it to the terminal, just having it selected, then executing a command to display the location there?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing to fit here is a nautilus plugin.

1. Install python-nautilus

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python-nautilus
   ```
2. Create a plugin "TestExtension.py"

   ```
   sudo nano /usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions/TestExtension.py
   ```

   This extension will call your script whenever the selection changes and pass the selection one by one as second command argument `$1`:

   ```
   from gi.repository import Nautilus, GObject
   import os

   class ColumnExtension(GObject.GObject, Nautilus.MenuProvider):
       def __init__(self):
           pass

       def menu_activate_cb(self, menu, file):
           print "menu_activate_cb",file

       def get_file_items(self, window, files):

           for file in files:
               uri = file.get_uri()
               if uri.startswith("file:///"):
                   os.system("yourscript_path"+" \""+uri[7:]+"\"")

           return
   ```

   Or you may make a list, combine them as single string, then `export` it as `env` variable. So current selection will be accessible for all other scripts. (security hole)
3. Kill nautilus

   ```
   pkill nautilus
   ```

**Reference:**

- [nautilus-python Reference Manual](https://projects-old.gnome.org/nautilus-python/documentation/html/index.html)